# For loop isn't working but each component of the loop works

Tags: r

I am trying to set a for loop that would create boxplots for each gene in a dataframe. Each component of the loop is working. But as soon as I integrate the components in the loop, I don't get any results. I don't know what's going wrong with my code. Could you help me please ?

```
   Merged[, 1]   Apoa1   Fabp1   Aldob    Reg1    Car4    
1  Enterocyte  3052.41  4112.31 2342.12 7971.70 1519.83 
2  Enterocyte  635.88   2790.60 3523.84 4160.18 1081.47 
3  Enterocyte   46.35    702.58 1325.22  424.51  377.57 
4  Enterocyte  293.36    900.89 1966.51 3688.59  644.94 
5  Enterocyte   42.99   2921.10  800.14    1.94 1570.63 
6  Enterocyte    0.00    784.43 1219.74  213.08  640.65  

#(I don't have only enterocytes. This is just the first lines of the dataframe)

#To select the columns. Beginning at 1 because the first column is the cell type, not the TPM data
a=1
genenames <- unique(EC_relev$GeneName)

for (k in seq(1:length(genenames))){

  i <- genenames[k] # I give the name of the gene to i
  a <- a+1

# I create a dataframe for each gene containing the TPM data and the cell types
  Dataf <- as.data.frame(Merged2[,1])
  Dataf <- cbind(nam,Merged2[,3])
  colnames(nam) <- c("CellType","TPM")

# I do the boxplot
  ggplot(nam,aes(x=CellType,y=TPM))+ 
    labs(title = paste(i),x="Cell Types",y="Transcript per Million")+
    theme(axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(angle = 45,vjust = 1,hjust = 1,size = 10),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
          legend.text = element_text(size=11,face = "bold"),
          title = element_text(size = 13, face="bold"))+
    geom_boxplot()

}
```

Actually, when I run this, I don't get any result or error message. So I don't know what's going on.

Comment: I'm new to ggplot but wouldn't you need to define the `ggplot() +` and then loop the `geom`? Also reproducible data is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `print` the plot explicitely when they are inside `for` loops or `function`s.

change the plotting by this:

```
g <-  ggplot(nam,aes(x=CellType,y=TPM))+ 
    labs(title = paste(i),x="Cell Types",y="Transcript per Million")+
    theme(axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(angle = 45,vjust = 1,hjust = 1,size = 10),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
          legend.text = element_text(size=11,face = "bold"),
          title = element_text(size = 13, face="bold"))+
    geom_boxplot()
print(g)
```